# Problem with height of element while making an accordion layout using only vanilla JS

Tags: javascript, css

I have a task of making an accordion layout using only vanilla JS.

The issue I have is when I reduce the window size and open a tab inside the accordion the height increases since the text is now bigger, so when I make it full screen again it remains the size it was when the window was smaller, which gives me a lot of whitespace.

```
function slideDown(element){
    element.classList.add('active');
    element.style.height="auto";
    element.style.display='block';
    element.style.margin = "auto";

    var height = element.clientHeight + "px";

    element.style.height = "0px";
    element.style.marginTop="16px";
    element.style.marginBottom="16px";

    setTimeout(() => {
        element.style.height = height;
    }, 0) }
```

So the issue here, every time I open up a tab in the accordion, the "auto" reads the height of the content (which is always bigger in a smaller window, in order to fit the paragraph into the screen), so when I make it full screen again, it remains that size until I repeat this action.

I need a solution that will change the height of the element depending on the window size, or another way to determine the height of the content when I use the slide down animation in the accordion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to make this dynamic, you can detect that the window was resized and recalculate your element height.

```
window.onresize = function(event) {
    // resize your element here
};
```

See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/resize_event